# Need help regarding RSS Feed and wordpress

Tags: c#, asp.net

i need to read rss feed from wordpress url. so here is the url
http://bbaremancareers.wordpress.com/feed/

i just need to pick up title,content,publish date,title hyperlink url and media file url etc.

i just could fetch only title and content but i need to know how can i fetch also 
publish date,title hyperlink url and media file url.

### here  is my code

```
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://bbaremancareers.wordpress.com/feed/");
        var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load<SyndicationFeed>(reader);

        Console.WriteLine("Latest posts from " + feed.Title.Text);

        foreach (var item in feed.Items)
        {
            string strTitle = item.Title.Text;
            string strContent = item.Summary.Text;
        }
    }
```

so please add more code in my existing code to fetch extra data like publish date,title hyperlink url and media file url from the wordpress url http://bbaremancareers.wordpress.com/feed/.

please help. thanks

Comment: who gave me the negative vote & why.

Comment: I don't know, wasn't me. Shame I didn't get any upvotes either lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        var reader = XmlReader.Create("http://bbaremancareers.wordpress.com/feed/");
        var feed = SyndicationFeed.Load<SyndicationFeed>(reader);

        Console.WriteLine("Latest posts from " + feed.Title.Text);

        foreach (var item in feed.Items)
        {
            string strTitle = item.Title.Text;
            string strContent = item.Summary.Text;
            DateTime publishDate = item.PublishDate.DateTime;
            string linkUrl = item.Links[0].Uri.ToString();
        }
```

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i need to show PublishDate as format like Wednesday, February 01, 2012 1:22 PM but my date is showing like 2/1/2012 7:52:05 AM +00:00. so tell me what to change or how to format my date as a result it should look like February 01, 2012 1:22 instead of 2/1/2012 7:52:05 AM +00:00.

Comment: string publishDateFormatted = string.Format("{0:MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm}", publishDate);